# Match Dynamic String with grep in OSX

Tags: regex, grep

I'm on OS X and trying to use grep to get the filename of a dynamically created sprite name printed in a CSS file.

I can't figure out how to match the following string:
`ui/sprite-sba62176be8.png`

The only part that changes is the string between the hyphen and the .png

Comment: I don't know how else to clarify it, users answered my question perfectly and understood what I asked so I don't see what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this (thanks to @mtm for tweaks from my original regex):

```
grep -o "ui/sprite-[^.]\+\.png" yourfile
```

**Explanation**

- `[^.]` is a negated character class that matches any character that is not a dot.
- The `+` quantifier means "one or more" of what precedes it. With `grep` in basic regex mode (the default), it needs to be escaped: `\+`
- The `o` flag prints **o** nly the match (not the whole line).

Note that on some implementations of grep you would need the `P` flag (which activates Perl mode):

```
grep -oP "ui/sprite-[^.]+\.png" yourfile
```

Comment: Definitely a better answer than mine +1

Comment: No problem :) It's not about reputation but about good answers and sharing knowledge, and yours was by far better.

Comment: BSD `grep` doesn't support `-P`. `grep -o "ui/sprite-[^.]\+.png"`

Comment: The `\+` is also important when using POSIX regex. Otherwise it is interperated as the character `+`

Comment: @mtm Thanks for that note, I haven't booted OSX today. Did you try it on OSX, without the `P` (can you confirm that it works)?

Comment: Why did you have to particularly do `[^.]+` rather than simply `.+`?

Comment: @sawa `.+` would match all the way to the end of the string, then the engine has to backtrack to allow the `.png` to match. So `[^.]+` is more efficient (an example of the "say what you mean" principle on this [Regex Style Guide](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html))

Comment: In basic POSIX RE's `+` is an ordinary character. Either use `grep -o "ui/sprite-[^.]\+\.png"`  or an extended re with your current formatting `grep -oE "ui/sprite-[^.]+\.png"`

Comment: @mtm That is the opposite of my experience of POSIX regex: `+` is a quantifier, unless escaped. Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, a linux box will be the same. You're describing extended (or modern) POSIX regex that `grep -E` or `egrep` defaults to. basic POSIX regex that `grep` defaults to treats `+` `|` and `?` as plain characters as well as a lot more. [Second last paragraph in the description](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE). Many require `\\` "magic" to give them regex meaning.

Comment: No probs. I think most ppl use `*` which works as expected so they never notice =)

Comment: Although using `[^.]+` is going to be more efficient than `.+`, they are not equivalent : the regex using `[^.]+` cannot match `ui/sprite-abcd.efg.123.png` which is not impossible base on OP's question

Comment: @AdrianShum I'm well aware of the difference and chose `[^.]+` because from the question, it seemed unlikely that dots would enter the suffix `-sba62176be8`. But you are right that if that string can contain dots, the regex needs a tweak.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've had a busy morning so couldn't keep up with the thread. Thanks for all the responses and the answer, it works like a charm. I'm not too sure why the question has been marked down though as I tried to find the answer, maybe I missed it but everything else I found didn't solve my problem!